# C# TableAdapter Insert Method Missing

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, tableadapter

I am using the C# VS2010 TableAdapter Wizard for my project to interface with my db.  I have generated my own Insert, Update and Delete commands for this adapter since it uses a join and can not generate its own.  I'm okay with that, but unfortunately when I created the Insert command I am not able to call the "Insert()" method on the tableadapter.  The other methods are working fine.

For example,

`this.joinTableAdapter = new MyTableAdapter();

this.joinTableAdapter.Insert() <-- does not exist.`

It was my understanding that once you create a valid insert command that this method should become visible on the table adapter.  Am I mistaken about this?  It is working for my update and delete command.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: I am going to guess **Insert()** is a static method. I for some reason cannot find DataTable on the msdn documentation.

Comment: I have been using DataSets for my project.  It does make mention of the .Update() method from the table adapter, but nothing mentioned about the .Insert().  Weird..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TableAdapter GenerateDbDirectMethods**

In addition to the InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, and DeleteCommand, TableAdapters are created with methods that can be executed directly against the database. These methods (TableAdapter.Insert, TableAdapter.Update, and TableAdapter.Delete) can be called directly to manipulate data in the database.

If you do not want to create these direct methods, set the TableAdapter's GenerateDbDirectMethods property to false (in the Properties window). Additional queries added to the TableAdapter are standalone queries — they do not generate these methods.

You'll find this option at the designer in the second last page.
**Create methods to send updates directly to the database**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dex7k4dw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

**Note**: This is not the same then clicking Advanced Options and click:

**Generate Insert, Update, and Delete statements**

When you select this option, the wizard will attempt to generate INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements based on the SELECT statement defined on the Generate SQL statements page.

---

**Edit:**

The TableAdapter cannot create insert,update and delete statements automatically when more than one table is involved in the main select query. There are several approaches if you need one or more columns of related tables, the best way depends on your requirement.

1. Add insert,update and delete queries manually to the TableAdapter. These methods can be called directly from an instance of the TableAdapter(f.e. `InsertUser(param1,param2)`)
2. Add insert,update and delete commands manually to the TableAdapter(designer or programmatically). These commands will be triggered implicitely from the TableAdapter when you call `Update`. The DataRow's [RowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate.aspx) determines which command will be triggered(f.e. Added->InsertCommand).
3. Select one table and join the tables via relations to other tables in the DataSet

For the third approach you could use [LINQ-To-DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) to join the related tables to get all needed columns(f.e. to create a DataSource for a GridView).

Comment: Hi tim, thanks for the quick response.  I am not able to use the GenerateDbDirectMethods since I have an innerjoin in my select statement, it won't work for that.  I have been through both of the links previously and they don't seem to explain why I would be having this problem.  I have manually added this Insert Query, but it is as though it doesn't recognize that the tableadapter has this command in it.

Comment: The TableAdapter cannot create insert,update and delete statements if more than table is involved in the main select query. You need to add according queries manually to the TableAdapter or only select one table and join the tables via relations in DataSet.

Comment: I don't want it to create them for me!  I HAVE manually created the insert command for the table adapter.  However, when I actually try to call the Insert from the table adapter, it doesn't exist!  Whyyyy!  My tableadapter.Update() works perfectly fine and I have done it the exact same way.  Sad panda :(.

Comment: @ImGreg: I think you are mixing adding a query to a TableAdapter(what i meant) and setting the InsertCommand(what you meant). The first can be called on the TableAdapter programmatically(f.e. you add a method `InsertUser(param1,param2,...)`). The latter will be called implicitely if you call `TableAdapter.Update(DataTable)` or `TableAdapter.Update(DataRow)` according to the current [RowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate.aspx) of every DataRow.

Comment: Ahhh I see.  You are right, I'm referring to the InsertCommand.  That is the way I was doing my Update and I would ideally like to the Insert the same way if possible.  Any idea why my way might not be working?  The other way of doing things complicates my program a lot. (ie. sending the query 30 properly converted datarows vs. sending it a dataset)

Comment: Have you seen that i've edited the answer to provide more informations? So you want to use the InsertCommand. As i've said, this we be called implicitely on `Updating` the DataTable/DataRow with the TableAdapter. Have you checked if `TableAdapter.Update` also inserts new rows if you've added them to the DataTable?

Comment: Sorry I missed the edit in your answer.  I have not tested this yet, but this makes a lot more sense what's going on.  The update method actually uses the insert method based on the rowstate.  Gotcha. I'll take it form here.  Thanks @Tim_Schmelter!

Answer (score 0):

There is a 4th way of working with JOIN queries.

For the table adapter's main query, omit the join. Then, add manually the columns to the data table and set their SourceColumn to the exact spelling of the fields you will add. Finally, add a new query to the table adapter that includes the join and call this query to fill the datatables in your application.

If this is too abbreviated, let me know. I'll elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the dataset click on the tableadaptor and check setting for property "GenerateDBDirectMethods" - Needs to be true